# JavaScript Datatable.JS / PHP MySQLi Sorting Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I'm using Datatables.JS to create a table of results returned from a MySQL database. When I return the results I'm trying to display them in DESC order. I have tried using ORDER BY DESC in my MySQLi query, this does return the results in the correct order, however when datatables is reading the results it's displaying them in some random order. So I've tried playing with the datatable settings to sort by my ID column but keep that column hidden. Whenever I attempt to add any code to handle the sorting, the sorting issue itself becomes resolved but all my pagination and buttons such as the buttons that allow the user to select which columns they would like to view just disappear. Below is the JS I'm using to select the features and setup I need for this datatable, can anyone show me how to add sorting by the ID column DESC into this without breaking it?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();

    //Buttons examples
    var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({
        pageLength: 20,
        lengthChange: false,
        searching: false,
        buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis']
    });

    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo('#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
} );
```

Adding ordering: and then selecting the column and defining the order seems to break all the other settings, I lose my pagination and default results length as well as all control buttons on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();

    //Buttons examples
    var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({

        pageLength: 20,
        lengthChange: false,
        searching: false,
        buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis'],
        order: [[ 1, desc ]]
    });

    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo('#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
} );
```

Comment: `desc` needs to be string `order: [[ 1, 'desc' ]]`

Comment: Tried that but with no success

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this solutions works and I still don't understand what caused the original problem but I did find a working piece of code posted under a loosely relevant problem on another forum. I combined that code with what I had already and it solved my problem. Hopefully this helps someone else out who may encounter the same issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable( {
        pageLength: 20,
        lengthChange: false,
        searching: false,
        ordering: true,
        order: [[ 3, 'DESC' ]],
        dom: 'B1frtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy',
            'excel',
            'pdf',
            'colvis'
        ]
    });

      table.buttons().container()
     .appendTo('#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');  
});
```

Just wanted to mention this JS was for a datatable that's part of the Fonik Bootstrap Admin Template.